# Push notification is causing crashing parse app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

The `push notification` runs perfect when app is running and open but if push notification is send when app is closed or not running, the app crashes and "app X unfortunately stopped" is displayed.

i am pasting the logcat output to see the error details, pls see last entries in log cat:

```
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): Process: com.ifreedomapp.v3, PID:25004
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2887)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at com.parse.PushService.onCreate(PushService.java:230)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): ... 8 more
12-14 01:13:50.802: I/Process(25004): Sending signal. PID: 25004 SIG: 9
```

Steps to reproduce:
(i added the parse initialization to my activity's OnCrete and edited my manifest as instructed in parse docs)

After that i compiled and run my app.
1. the app is open and i send a push notification from parse panel, it is received and works well.
2. Then i close the app and go android home screen, then i send another push notification from parse panel.
3. the notification does not appear but "X app has unfortunately stopped" is displayed. (X = app name)
4. Again if i open the app and send the notification from panel, it is received but if app is closed or in background, it does not display notification, it crashes.

Solution given on Github:

Parse.initialize(Context) should be done in your Application#onCreate(), not your Activity#onCreate(Bundle) as per our docs: http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/Parse.html#initialize(android.content.Context)

You're getting this issue since Push Notifications wake the Application, but not your Activity, which means you're getting to Parse code before initialization.

i did that, i now tried adding initialization to OnCreate of application and not of activity,

But then after running my app, it is not getting any push notifications, its not registering the device only.

Here is some part of my code:

```
public class StatusActivity extends
com.MainBase.TabbedActivityBase {

public void onCreate() {
Parse.initialize(this, "", ""); // added my app credentials, removed here
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
  Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
}
public static final String BANNER_FILE_NAME = "bannerImage";

Context mContext;

private ImageView m_banner;


  // private boolean m_tunnelWholeDevicePromptShown = false;

      private InterstitialAd interstitial;  
      ImageView sharebtn;


  public StatusActivity() {
  super();
 m_eventsInterface = new Events();
}

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setContentView(R.layout.main);
// m_banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banner);
m_tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
m_toggleButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewToggle);
................ further code
```

Can anyone help me with this.

GitHub question: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/299

Comment: why do you have two `onCreate` in `StatusActivity`?

Comment: which line do you reach when you double click on this-`12-14 01:13:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(25004): at com.parse.PushService.onCreate(PushService.java:230)`(if you are using eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
1. Create a class of anyname say Constants which extends Application

```
public class Constants extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

2. Add this class name to application tag in manifest

> ```
> <application
>    android:name=".Constants">
> ```

And remove all the initialisation of  parse in the activities.